# Using a named pipe handle from multiple processes

Tags: windows, api, named-pipes, handle, multiprocess

Firstly, is it possible to write to a named pipe from two processes at once, using the same handle (or one duplicated using DuplicateHandle)?

And secondly, would it make any difference if one process performs asynchronous IO on the pipe, while the other performs synchronous IO?

From what I've tried, the process that reads from the pipe crashes.

Comment: It should either work or fail with a valid error code.  Can you show the code for the process at the read end of the pipe?